# EmberAuth sign in user on successful registration

Tags: api, authentication, ember.js

So I have EmberAuth all set up and working, and I'm implementing user registration. My API is set up to return an auth_token after a user is successfully registered, but I'm not quite sure how to move the app to a signedIn state.

The only solution I've come up with that really works is by calling `App.Auth.signIn` after successfully registering. Which is fine in the 'it works' sense, but it does involve what should be an unnecessary extra round trip to the server to sign the user in when I already have their auth token.

```
sendRegistration: () ->
  self = @
  $.post('/users', 
    user:
      email: @email,
      password: @password,
      password_confirmation: @passwordConfirmation)
  .done (response) ->
    App.Auth.signIn(
      data:
        email: self.email
        password: self.password
        remember: true
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ember-auth](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com) dev here.

Checkout the latest version (`v7.1.0`). It has a new feature that addresses this use case. You can now inject a signed in session directly if you already have all the authentication information. Just construct an expected "normal" server response, and feed it to `App.Auth.createSession()`.

Example: if the expected server response is

```
{"auth_token":"foo", "user_id": 1, "rmb_token":"bar"}
```

then call

```
App.Auth.createSession('{"auth_token":"foo", "user_id": 1, "rmb_token":"bar"}');
```

This injects the authentication session without hitting the server.

Its counterpart in clearing the session (again without hitting the server) is

```
App.Auth.destroySession();
```

The relevant section of the [docs](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com) is **Direct session injection / destruction**.

---

**Edit / update** for googlers: the syntax has changed with `ember-auth` `9.x` (latest release).

`auth` is now an object injected into routes, controllers, and views. So, if you are making the `createSession()` and `destroySession()` calls there, you can write

```
this.get('auth').createSession( /* args */ );
this.get('auth').destroySession( /* args */ );
```

The `createSession()` call can also be clarified to

```
this.get('auth').createSession({auth_token: 'foo', user_id: 1, rmb_token: 'bar'});
```

because both `createSession()` and `destroySession()` now accepts an object.

Comment: I love that you come in and answer these questions I have. Thanks so much!

Comment: @heartsentwined is there a way to make this session rememberable?

Comment: @SeifSallam answered you on github https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/issues/79#issuecomment-21004322 :)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing the same thing, making the additional request. But I did look into the implementation a little bit.

`Ember-Auth` has a [dummy request adapter](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/blob/master/lib/request/dummy.em) that just returns without making the request, using `opts.status` to determine what to return.

The trick is to switch out the `_request` adapter from the `Auth` instance, on demand.

The project uses EmberScript which is an extension of Coffeescript that I am unfamiliar with. So the extra request is good enough for now. :)